# How to access an int from a NSArray on the selected row?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Sorry if the title sounds confusing. But I'm trying to make an app that has a table view. Each row has its own button with its own set of points. I pretty much want the button to add the specific amount of points to a counter. However, I don't know how to access an int of an NSArray of the selected row. Here is the code:

```
@interface FBViewController ()

@end

@implementation FBViewController {

    NSArray *tablePoints;
    NSArray *tablePointLabel;
    int counter;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //A table that displays the points on the buttons
    tablePointLabel = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   @"10",
                   @"10",
                   @"10",
                   @"20",
                   @"20",
                   @"20",
                   @"30",
                   @"30",
                   @"50",
                   @"70",
                   @"100",
                   @"300",
                   @"300",
                   nil];

    //table of ints (points)
    tablePoints = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   @10,
                   @10,
                   @10,
                   @20,
                   @20,
                   @20,
                   @30,
                   @30,
                   @50,
                   @70,
                   @100,
                   @300,
                   @300,
                   nil];

    counter = 0;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [tableData count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"FBCell";

    FBCell *cell = (FBCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FBCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }


    UIButton *pointButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    pointButton.frame = CGRectMake(250.0f, 5.0f, 75.0f, 30.0f);
    [pointButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [pointButton setTitle:[tablePointLabel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:pointButton];
    [pointButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(addPoint:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    return cell;
}

-(IBAction)addPoint:(id)sender {


    counter + [tablePoints objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] = counter; 
    **//This is where I have an issue. indexPath.row does not work for int arrays. what do i do???**


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of ways to improve this (including suggestions offered by rmaddy)

My recommendation is instead of instantiating a uibutton (that I'm guessing is equal to the height/width of each table row, is to implement

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//increments counte
counter += [tablePoints[indexPath.row] intValue];
}
```

Moreover, for the row label, just stick in uilabel, and for (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath, set the label according to the array value. In fact, you don't even need to declare two identical arrays, just repurpose the same one.

Comment: Thanks to you and scottdev! I used this method instead. It seemed simpler. Thank you!!

Comment: We all have to start somewhere. Glad to help. (don't forget to accept an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

A NSArray holds objects, not values. In your case it holds NSNumber objects which in turn holds the values.

Use the indexPath.row to get the NSNumber and then get the value.

```
NSNumber *numberObject = [tablePoints objectAtIndex:myIndex];
int myInt = [numberObject intValue]; // NSNumber covers a range of different types of values
```

One question is where you're obtaining your indexPath.row and is it valid at that point.

Comment: Actually, his array holds NSString objects.

Comment: @OwenHartnett No, the `tablePoints` array hold `NSNumber` objects.

Comment: My mistake, I only saw the tablePointLabel array and assumed he was using that. The arrays hold duplicate values - he only really needs one.